# Comparing pd.Series and getting, what appears to be, unusual results when the series contains None

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am wondering why comparing two identical series with `None` value returns False:

```
pd.Series(['x', 'y', None]) == pd.Series(['x', 'y', None])

0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

I would expect all of results to be True. If I create an array, from the series, and compare I get the expected result:

```
pd.Series(['x', 'y', None]).values == pd.Series(['x', 'y', None]).values

array([ True,  True,  True])
```

Why are the two identical series with `None` not equal to each other? Am I missing something?

I would expect this behavior with `np.nan` because `np.nan != np.nan`; however, `None == None`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [by design](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20442#issuecomment-375247173):

> see the warnings box: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html
>
> This was done quite a while ago to make the behavior of nulls
>   consistent, in that they don't compare equal. This puts `None` and
>   `np.nan` on an equal (though not-consistent with python, BUT consistent
>   with numpy) footing.
>
> So this is not a bug, rather a consequence of stradling 2 conventions.
>
> I suppose the documentation could be slightly enhanced.

For equality of series containing null values, use [`pd.Series.equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.equals.html):

```
pd.Series(['x', 'y', None]).equals(pd.Series(['x', 'y', None]))  # True
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.