# Why does pandas merge on NaN?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I recently asked a question regarding missing values in pandas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53549030/comparing-pd-series-and-getting-what-appears-to-be-unusual-results-when-the-se) and was directed to a [github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20442#issuecomment-375247173). After reading through that page and the [missing data documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html).

I am wondering why `merge` and `join` treat NaNs as a match when "they don't compare equal": `np.nan != np.nan`

```
# merge example
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[np.nan, 'match'], 'col2':[1,2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[np.nan, 'no match'], 'col3':[3,4]})
pd.merge(df,df2, on='col1')

    col1    col2    col3
0   NaN      1       3

# join example with same dataframes from above
df.set_index('col1').join(df2.set_index('col1'))

      col2  col3
col1        
NaN     1   3.0
match   2   NaN
```

However, NaNs in `groupby` are excluded:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[np.nan, 'match', np.nan], 'col2':[1,2,1]})
df.groupby('col1').sum()

       col2
col1    
match   2
```

Of course you can `dropna()` or `df[df['col1'].notnull()]` but I am curious as to why NaNs are excluded in some pandas operations like `groupby` and not others like `merge`, `join`, `update`, and `map`?

Essentially, as I asked above, why does `merge` and `join` match on `np.nan` when they do not compare equal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yeah, this is *definitely* a bug. See [GH22491](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22491) which documents exactly your issue, and [GH22618](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22618) which notes the problem is also observed with `None`. based on the discussions, this does not appear to be intended behaviour.

A quick source dive shows that the issue ***might*** be inside the [`_factorize_keys`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py#L1591-L1651) function in `pandas/core/reshape/merge.py`. This function appears to factorise the keys to determine what rows are to be matched with each other.

Specifically, this portion

```
# NA group
lmask = llab == -1
lany = lmask.any()
rmask = rlab == -1
rany = rmask.any()

if lany or rany:
    if lany:
        np.putmask(llab, lmask, count)
    if rany:
        np.putmask(rlab, rmask, count)
    count += 1
```

...seems to be the culprit. NaN keys are identified as a valid category (with categorical value equal to `count`).

Disclaimer: I am not a pandas dev, and this is only my speculation; so the real issue could be something else. But from first glance, this seems like it.

Comment: Agree that this is not the correct behavior, especially if we compare to SQL or other languages. I really think they should at least put a warning when using df.merge(). Just to confirm this is still being discussed in the github developers page, the issue number is now this: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32306#issuecomment-966763326