# Filter pandas data frame for NaN value without isnull

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list `A`:

```
A = [nan, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

And a pandas data frame `df`:

```
index     X        Y
0         A        NaN
1         B        2
2         C        6
3         D        4
4         E        3
```

I'd like to create a list comprehension to get a list of the index where each value in the list equals column Y. Usually I would do this:

```
B = [df[df.Y == x].index[0] for x in A]
```

However, this doesn't work for the first element of A, nan. Obviously I could do the above with a normal for loop and using isnull, as below, but is there a way to do it with a list comprehension?

```
B = []
for x in A:
    if pd.isnull(x):
        B.append(df[pd.isnull(df.Y)].index[0])
    else:
        B.append(df[df.Y == x])
```

Expected result:

```
B = [0,1,4,3,2]
```

Comment: can you show how your output should look like?

Answer (score 1):

Giving you exactly what you want (and by essentially just re-purposing your existing if statement), try:

`B = [df[pd.isnull(df.Y)].index[0] if pd.isnull(x) else df[df.Y == x].index[0] for x in A]`

Answer (score 0):

Using `merge` , about how it work check the link [Why does pandas merge on NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688988/why-does-pandas-merge-on-nan)

```
A = [np.nan, 2, 3, 4, 6]
pd.DataFrame({'Y':A}).merge(df,how='left')
Out[394]: 
     Y  index  X
0  NaN      0  A
1  2.0      1  B
2  3.0      4  E
3  4.0      3  D
4  6.0      2  C
```