# Merge on Nan - The bug is the behavior I want. Should I worry about future correction?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

In **Pandas**, `pd.Nan != pd.Nan`, Yet for now, merging to dataframe, the Nan will be merge together.

As reported in the question [Why does pandas merge on NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688988/why-does-pandas-merge-on-nan), the normal behavior should be to not merge on that. The question is discussed [on the Pandas issue tracker](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32306).

*From It_is_chris:*

> ```
> # merge example
> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[np.nan, 'match'], 'col2':[1,2]})
> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[np.nan, 'no match'], 'col3':[3,4]})
> pd.merge(df,df2, on='col1')
>
>     col1    col2    col3
> 0   NaN      1       3
> ```

Now that we know that, In my code, I need to merge on the Nan as well. I could use the glitch in Pandas, but In the future, could the behavior change and then break my code?

What is the best option to prevent that?

Thanks

Comment: If empty cells carry implicit information for you, you could make this explicit by filling (`.fillna()`) them with some standard value expressing the information (e.g. "no department", "other", ...).
Then you will face no problem with the join/merge.

Comment: Please [do not gratuitously add tags to the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/1968). They belong *in the tags list*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly pointed out, in future, there is a possibility of not being able to join on NaN. Depending on the programming language, this behavior changes.

The easiest future-proof solution would be to replace NaN with "NA" or a similar string. You may replace it back to to NaN post merging if required.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[np.nan, 'match'], 'col2':[1,2]}).fillna("NA")
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[np.nan, 'no match'], 'col3':[3,4]}).fillna("NA")
pd.merge(df,df2, on='col1')
```