# Pandas join with multi-index and NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using Pandas 2.1.3.

I am trying to join two DataFrames on multiple index levels, and one of the index levels has NA's. The minimum reproducible example looks something like this:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({
    'idx_a':['A', 'A', 'B'],
    'idx_b':['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'],
    'idx_c': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    'x':[10, 20, 30]
}).set_index(['idx_a', 'idx_b', 'idx_c'])

b = pd.DataFrame({
    'idx_b':['gamma', 'delta', 'epsilon', np.nan, np.nan],
    'idx_c': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    'y':[100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
}).set_index(['idx_b', 'idx_c'])

c = a.join(
    b,
    how='inner',
    on=['idx_b', 'idx_c']
)

print(a)
                    x
idx_a idx_b idx_c    
A     alpha 1.0    10
      beta  1.0    20
B     gamma 1.0    30

print(b)
                y
idx_b   idx_c     
gamma   1.0    100
delta   1.0    200
epsilon 1.0    300
NaN     1.0    400
        1.0    500

print(c)
                    x    y
idx_a idx_b idx_c         
B     gamma 1.0    30  100
            1.0    30  400
            1.0    30  500
```

I would have expected:

```
print(c)
                    x    y
idx_a idx_b idx_c         
B     gamma 1.0    30  100
```

Why is `join` matching on the `NaN` values?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688988/why-does-pandas-merge-on-nan

Comment: @Nick That question appears to refer to the issue of `NaN` matching on `NaN`, whereas in the case above, it looks like `NaN` is matching on a non-`NaN` value. Do I misunderstand?

Comment: That's why I didn't close as a dupe, that question just shows there's a generic issue with merging/joining with `NaN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve your problem by removing the indexes and using `merge` instead of `join`:

```py
a = pd.DataFrame({
    'idx_a':['A', 'A', 'B'],
    'idx_b':['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'],
    'idx_c': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    'x':[10, 20, 30]
})

b = pd.DataFrame({
    'idx_b':['gamma', 'delta', 'epsilon', np.nan, np.nan],
    'idx_c': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    'y':[100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
})

c = a.merge(b, on=['idx_b', 'idx_c'], how='inner')
```

Output:

```
  idx_a  idx_b  idx_c   x    y
0     B  gamma    1.0  30  100
```

If you want to keep the indexes on `a` and `b` as they are in the question you can do this (thanks @mozway):

```
c = (a
    .reset_index()
    .merge(b.reset_index(), on=['idx_b', 'idx_c'], how='inner')
    .set_index(list(dict.fromkeys(a.index.names+b.index.names)))
)
```

Output:

```
                    x    y
idx_a idx_b idx_c
B     gamma 1.0    30  100
```

Comment: Using OP's input this would give `c = a.reset_index().merge(b.reset_index(), on=['idx_b', 'idx_c'], how='inner').set_index(list(dict.fromkeys(a.index.names+b.index.names)))`

Comment: @mozway yeah, I kind of figured OP was just setting index for the purpose of the join, but that would definitely do the job otherwise. I'll update the answer, thanks

Comment: Thanks. This is a good workaround. It's funny. I tend to use `join` instead of `merge` because the strictness of the former tends to keep me out of trouble. In this case, that instinct didn't serve me well!

Comment: @tcquinn no worries - I'm glad it was helpful. Definitely ironic about your choice of operator! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create an additional index level that indicates whether `idx_b` contains a `NaN`, use that index level as part of the join, then drop the added index level.

```py
a['idx_b_nan'] = a.index.get_level_values('idx_b').isna()
b['idx_b_nan'] = b.index.get_level_values('idx_b').isna()

a = a.set_index('idx_b_nan', append=True)
b = b.set_index('idx_b_nan', append=True)

c = a.join(
    b,
    how='inner',
    on=['idx_b', 'idx_c', 'idx_b_nan'],
).droplevel('idx_b_nan')

print(c)
```

This outputs:

```
                    x    y
idx_a idx_b idx_c         
B     gamma 1.0    30  100
```

This behavior is due to a bug in Pandas that's been around since 2019. See [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25138) GitHub issue and [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32306) GitHub issue. The former issue was closed to centralize discussion in the latter, but the latter issue is still open at the time this answer was authored.

Comment: Thanks. This is also a good workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't want NaNs to match, you could first drop them:

```
def nona(x):
    return x[x.index.to_frame().notna().all(axis=1)]

out = nona(a).join(nona(b), how='inner')
```

Output:

```
                    x    y
idx_b idx_c idx_a         
gamma 1.0   B      30  100
```

Comment: Thanks. For my current use case, I don't actually need to preserve the `NaN`'s, so this is actually what I'll do.